# how to use sklearn when target variable is a proportion

Tags: python, scikit-learn

There are standard ways of predicting proportions such as logistic regression (without thresholding) and beta regression. There have already been discussions about this:

http://scikit-learn-general.narkive.com/4dSCktaM/using-logistic-regression-on-a-continuous-target-variable

http://scikit-learn-general.narkive.com/lLVQGzyl/beta-regression

I cannot tell if there exists a work-around within the `sklearn` framework.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There exists a workaround, but it is not intrinsically *within* the `sklearn` framework.

If you have a proportional target variable (value range 0-1) you run into two basic difficulties with scikit-learn:

- Classifiers (such as logistic regression) deal with class labels as target variables only. As a workaround you could simply threshold your probabilities to 0/1 and interpret them as class labels, but you would lose a lot of information.
- Regression models (such as linear regression) do not restrict the target variable. You can train them on proportional data, but there is no guarantee that the output on unseen data will be restricted to the 0/1 range. However, in this situation, there is a powerful work-around (below).

There are different ways to mathematically formulate logistic regression. One of them is the [generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#As_a_generalized_linear_model), which basically defines the logistic regression as a normal linear regression on logit-transformed probabilities. Normally, this approach requires sophisticated mathematical optimization because the probabilities are unknown and need to be estimated along with the regression coefficients.

In your case, however, the probabilities are known. This means you can simply transform them with `y = log(p / (1 - p))`. Now they cover the full range from `-oo` to `oo` and can serve as the target variable for a [LinearRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) model [*]. Of course, the model output then needs to be transformed again to result in probabilities `p = 1 / (exp(-y) + 1)`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


class LogitRegression(LinearRegression):

    def fit(self, x, p):
        p = np.asarray(p)
        y = np.log(p / (1 - p))
        return super().fit(x, y)

    def predict(self, x):
        y = super().predict(x)
        return 1 / (np.exp(-y) + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # generate example data
    np.random.seed(42)
    n = 100
    x = np.random.randn(n).reshape(-1, 1)
    noise = 0.1 * np.random.randn(n).reshape(-1, 1)
    p = np.tanh(x + noise) / 2 + 0.5

    model = LogitRegression()
    model.fit(x, p)

    print(model.predict([[-10], [0.0], [1]]))
    # [[  2.06115362e-09]
    #  [  5.00000000e-01]
    #  [  8.80797078e-01]]
```

- There are also numerous other alternatives. Some non-linear regression models can work naturally in the 0-1 range. For example [Random Forest Regressors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) will never exceed the target variables' range they were trained with. Simply put probabilities in and you will get probabilities out. Neural networks with appropriate output activation functions (`tanh`, I guess) will also work well with probabilities, but if you want to use those there are more specialized libraries than sklearn.

[*] You could in fact plug in *any* [linear](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.linear_model) regression model which can make the method more powerful, but then it no longer is exactly equivalent to logistic regression.

Comment: Could you please explain what should be done about training / test data which contains a probability of 0 or 1? y is -inf and div by zero in these cases.

Comment: @JakeDrew The easiest solution would be to replace *0* with *e* and *1* with *1-e*, where *e* is a very small number. (You can also sanitize the probabilities with `p = p * e + 0.5 * e`). I guess `e = 1e-16` would work well.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I was experimenting exactly as you suggested earlier.  I found that for the range p = (0, 1) using .009 and .991 for values of 0 and 1 produce an 10-fold cv MAE = 0.059 or 5.9%.  Using p =  9e-16 on the same data drives the MAE up to 0.2266 or 22.6%.  The precision of e seems to have a huge impact on the mean absolute error.  When y = np.log(p / (1 - p)) and p=0.991 then y=6.9.  When p= 9e-16, y=36.7.  Perhaps I am over-fitting to my own dataset?

Comment: @JakeDrew Overfitting is always a realistic possibility ;) The most extreme values have a lot of leverage on the regression and on the error estimates. There is not much general advice I can give here... best plot the variously transformed data (*x* vs *y*) and the resulting regression lines to get a feeling for what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found GLM family=binomial(link='logit') in R which accepts probabilities.  However, my best results were using Random Forest Regression and SVR in sklearn.  RFR produces an MAE of 2.42% during 10-fold cv while SVR was at 1.87 MAE even with a max() prediction of 100.93.

Comment: p/(1-p) in the answer should be log(p/(1-p))

Comment: Thank you for a great answer (tho I'm a bit late to the party). Any idea if there's an official term or name for using a different linear model for logit-transformed dependant variables?

Comment: @penelope I don't know any official term, but unofficially I would start by calling the whole thing a [Generalized Linear Model (GLM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model). Then I would proceed by noting that these different linear models are actually only different algorithms for fitting a linear model. Depending on the used algorithm or it's properties I would construct a final name like *Regularized GLM*, *Sparse GLM*, *Ridge GLM*, *Lasso GLM*, etc.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, this sounds quite reasonable. Another question, if you know: the info about the output of certain regressors is a bit difficult to find from their sklearn documentation (i.e. for the Random Forests, it only mentions being bounded by the training examples in an example page, not directly in the documentation). Do you know if there are any other standard sklearn regressors that would likewise limit their output according to the training examples, except Random Forests?

Comment: @penelope No,  I just mentioned Random Forests because I know them very well ;)

Comment: How would you "test" the LogitRegressor? I assume mean-squared-error is not usefull in the logit domaine

Comment: If I understood this correctly, this is basically the same fit/predict formulation for Logistic Regression, except for the loss function where here you rely on MSE from linear regression while logistic regression minimizes the log loss on a 1 or 0 truth label.

Comment: @CutePoison [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy)

Comment: @SriK In logistic regression `p` is a latent variable which requires iterative minimization of the loss function. Here `p` is known, which allows us to minimize the MSE in a closed form solution.

Comment: How would I determine the 95% confidence interval with this?

Comment: @HaikalYeo the confidence interval of what?

Comment: Of the prediction.

Comment: @HaikalYeo Maybe it's possible to take the confidence interval of the linear regression and apply the transformation. Alternatively, bootstrapping should always work.