# Out-of-core multiclass classifier with class probabilities as targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I'm working on a project for which I'd like to use scikit-learn to train an out-of-core multiclass classifier. The prediction target is an array of class probabilities probabilities, e.g.

```
Y = [[0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
     [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
     [0.2, 0.1, 0.7],
     [0.2, 0.2, 0.6], ...]
```

In other words, `Y` is normalized such that `Y.sum(axis=1) = [1, 1, 1, 1, ...]`.

I noticed that scikit-learn has the [`OneVsRestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) wrapper class, which I thought might be helpful. It seems to support [`partial_fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-partial-fit) as long as the underlying binary classifier supports it too (I would use [`SGDClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)).

When I feed this target `Y` into the classifier, however, I get some errors about having to pass the classes upon first call of `partial_fit`:

```py
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier())
clf.partial_fit(X, Y)  # raises ValueError
```

The error reads *"classes must be passed on the first call to partial_fit"*. So I tried passing an array of class labels:

```py
clf.partial_fit(X, Y, classes=[0, 1, 2])  # raises another ValueError
```

This raises another error saying that `[0.1, 0.5, ...]` are absent from the classes `[0, 1, 2]`.

I also tried the batch `fit` method, but it seems that it's not implemented for that method either.

## Question

Does anyone know if this is possible in scikit-learn? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: Classifiers in general expect class labels where you are trying to pass class probabilities. Workarounds are possible... they might or might not be applicable in your case. See [how to use sklearn when target variable is a proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44234682/3005167) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> This raises another error saying that [0.1, 0.5, ...] are absent from the classes [0, 1, 2]

`Y` should be a vector of shape (n_samples,). Since your unique `classes` are `[0,1,2]`, `partial_fit()` expects these values to be present in `Y`.

If max probability determines your output class, you can modify the train set Y as `Y = np.amax(Y, axis=1)` and pass that to `partial_fit()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I feel like the argmax will throw away too much information. What I'll do instead is replicate each data point say 100 times (my dataset isn't huge), whereby I sample the targets according to `np.random.choice(classes, p=[0.1, 0.5, 0.4], size=100)` etc.