# Python package to perform logistic regression with continuous target between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression

my inputs are feature vectors, and my outputs/targets are floats between 0 and 1 for training.

I am familiar that XGBRFRegressor and XGBRegressor are capable of this, but I am seeking logistic regression equivalent rather than using gradient boosting. I guess I could manually do the log transformations turning it into a standard linear regression problem, but seeking to see if there is already a solution for this.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: There's logistic regression module in `scikit-learn`.

Comment: logistic regression by sklearn only permits binary targets

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted. This is how logistic regression works due to how logistic function is defined. Why do you want to do logistic regression if you already can use XGBRegressor? I'm pretty sure the latter will give much better results.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by transforming to linear scale then training using any regression method, and then transforming back with a log transformation.

see an example at [how to use sklearn when target variable is a proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234682/how-to-use-sklearn-when-target-variable-is-a-proportion)