# Is there a way to constrain the predicted values when using sklearn LinearRegression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression

I'm using sklearn Linear regression to predict the percentage value of a variable. Currently the prediction outputs give values of below 0% and above 100%. Is there any way to constrain these values to between 0 and 100? I saw another post which recommended the use of a Multiple Logistic Regression for categorical variables, but that wouldn't be useful here as the percentage values are continuous.

Also, would this be an acceptable thing to constrain for? For example, would all below 0 and above 100 predicted values be set to 0 and 100 respectively, in which case the R squared stats would change, or would applying a constrain keep the statistics the same with any out-of-range points discarded?

My current code is:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)

x = df.loc[:,np.concatenate((["independent var 1","independent var 2"],categorical variable))]
y = df.dependent_%_var

# fit the model to the data
model.fit(x, y)

# and plotting what this relationship looks like 
visualizer = ResidualsPlot(model)
visualizer.fit(x, y)  # Fit the training data to the model
visualizer.poof()
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you showed the output of the visualizer plot as well as adding the data (defining `df`) at least a few rows. As is, we cant run your code to try to reproduce this problem

Comment: @TCArlen thanks for your response. The code works well, it's just I was wondering if there's anything I could specify to bound the prediction between the values of 0 and 100. It would be difficult to reproduce the problem by posting the dataframe here as my dataset has thousands of lines and 13 categories and I think it will be complex to recreate the outputs easily with a small simplified data set. I'll experiment and see if I can get a mini dataframe that does the same.

Comment: Interesting question, but since it's about the choice of model, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, if the output is supposed to be a proportion, the right thing to do is to choose a model accordingly. Logistic regression is one possibility. When you repost your question, you can help others help you by saying more about what you are trying to do and what data you have available.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks, I'll re-post in stats exchange too. The first part of the question does relate to coding as I'd like additional syntax (e.g. a parameter to add in the LinearRegression call) that allows for the output to be bounded without changing the model. Perhaps I do need to find another model though. The output is supposed to be a proportion. However, although it is a proportion it's also a continuous output between 0 and 100 with any fractional value allowed so a logistic regression model won't be appropriate as that requires categorical outputs, e.g. 0 to 5%, 5 to 10% etc

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks so much for identifying the right term as being 'proportion' rather than percentage. That has helped my search a lot, e.g. I found this answer which is putting me on the right track: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-does-one-do-regression-when-the-dependent-variable-is-a-proportion/

Comment: and this seems to be along the lines of what I'm looking for (I'll have a go at it soon): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234682/how-to-use-sklearn-when-target-variable-is-a-proportion

Comment: Looks like you are looking into GLM's, that's great, that's an appropriate model. At this point, the only comment I have is that it seems like you've misunderstood what logistic regression is; it doesn't require categorized outputs. While it's true that LR models are typically trained on 0/1 data, that isn't a requirement.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier. I'll continue investigating GLMs and Logistic regression. I've created a follow up question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081571/is-there-a-way-to-suitably-adjust-this-sklearn-logistic-regression-function-to-a) and when I find a good answer I'll post it back here too.

Comment: Looks like you have solved your current problem, that's great. Followups are more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com since what you are really asking about are conceptual, modeling questions. Good luck and have fun.